# How draw signature (click, hold and move mouse) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, signature

I am writing tests for front-end part of rails application. 
I use selenium and capybara for testing some front-end features.

Now I need to test online signature on html page. So, I have and element with `.signature` css class. I know that I can run javascript in browser when tests is running:

```
page.evaluate_script "some js code goes here"
```

**Question:**
How can I do this things with pure javascript or jQuery:

1. calculate size of `.signature` element
2. Then move mouse into this element
3. Then draw a signature (then click and hold mouse button and move mouse inside of element borders)

Thanks!

Comment: you can try to see this link http://keith-wood.name/signature.html

Comment: @OliSoproniB. It does not suit for me, cause I am writing ruby tests. Project doesn't use jQuery UI Signature plugin on production. So I can use only pure javascript of jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

I found myself in your situation and run into your question :)

I don't know how deep do you want to test. In my case, I am using this plugin: [signature_pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad)

I have a box with a default text when the user has not signed yet, then when he signs I show the option to delete the signature. So I check for those texts to know if there is a signature at all.

I could click on the signature pad and the app recognised the clicks!

```
find('#signature-box').click
find('#signature-box').click
find('#signature-box').click
```

(They are basic capybara finders and instructions)
This worked for me. It might or might not work for you because you have a different signature system, because you want to see a **real** signature, but this could help someone.